# Unicode character picker but for a custom selection of characters

Tags: windows-10, unicode

I frequently find myself googling for certain unicode symbols like "unicode right arrow" or "unicode ge" or "unicode checkbox" and then copy-pasting what I find into whatever piece of text I'm in the process of writing (email, code comment, ...). This is the least annoying method I've been able to come up with so far.

What I'd *actually* like to have and have so far failed to find is some sort of popup window invoked by a keyboard shortcut that will display a selection of my favorite symbols so I can chose one of them, preferably just by using the arrow keys and return. I don't even need the ability to search through all available unicode characters in that window, I'd be happy to just add them the first time I need them. Usually I just need one of the same, say, 20 of my go-to symbols.

So what I'm looking for may be quite close to the emoji picker tht can be invoked by typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. I just don't need the emojis, I need a set of my own favorite symbols. If there is some sort of AHK script that creates a popup window with my symbols, that'd be fine, too.

What I'm *not* looking for:

- Remembering individual codes so I can Alt-1234 the characters.
- Searching for characters in some sort of "Special Characters" window inside of Word
- The tool BabelMap. Way too complicated.
- The emoji picker
- [What Luke Smith does with dmenu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCEXY46t3OA&feature=youtu.be&t=86). Unfortunately, I'm stuck with Windows at work :(

Thank you for any recommendations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I finally found a very nice solution: https://lintalist.github.io/

It's actually written in Autohotkey and is capable of much more than I need but also does what I need very well. Basically, when I want to enter one of my favourite symbols, I will press CapsLock (finally a use for that key) and then choose a symbol from the list.

You're welcome, me.

[image: Lintalist showing my favourite symbols]