# Unicode character picker

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, unicode

Too many times I find myself googling "Unicode " to find a Unicode character suitable for my needs. I'm now trying to replace that silly procedure with something more reproducible and reliable, so I'm looking for a Unicode character picker that works offline on Windows.

Requirements:

- pick Unicode characters by scrolling through them
- support typing descriptive names like "cross" or "box"
- works offline, i.e. locally installs its own Unicode database
- works on Windows
- is gratis
- no ads; donation button is acceptable

Ideal:

- Regions like "math symbols", "greek" or similar as in Microsoft Word.

Optional:

- LaTeX support, e.g. search for "alpha", find lower case α and upper case Α, Latex `\alpha` and `\Alpha`, respectively.

I've tried:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, but it's too focused on Emojis
- builtin Windows tool `charmap`, but it can scroll only. Searching by descriptive name is not possible
- Microsoft Word symbol table, but it can scroll only. Searching by descriptive name is not possible. At least is has regions like "math".
- [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/79508/small-and-fast-unicode-character-picker-with-support-for-tex-math) is almost identical but for Linux. In addition, I don't necessarily need LaTeX support, although it would really be nice.
- [Lintalist](https://lintalist.github.io/) as [suggested here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/74092/unicode-character-picker-but-for-a-custom-selection-of-characters), but it does too much. I prefer a dedicated tool.
- [the R12A Unicode pickers](https://r12a.github.io/pickers/) are all online

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple PowerShell script and isn't a full-fledged app but it satisfies most of your requirements

Sample GUI output:

[image: Select-UniChar "math.*bold.*italic" | Out-GridView GUI result]

Sample console output:

```
PS D:\Unicode> Select-UniChar "cross.*mark|check" | Select-Object -First 8

Character Designation Name
--------- ----------- ----
⍻         U+237B      NOT CHECK MARK
⑇         U+2447      OCR AMOUNT OF CHECK
☑         U+2611      BALLOT BOX WITH CHECK
✅         U+2705      WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK
✓         U+2713      CHECK MARK
✔         U+2714      HEAVY CHECK MARK
❌         U+274C      CROSS MARK
❎         U+274E      NEGATIVE SQUARED CROSS MARK

PS D:\Unicode> Select-UniChar "alpha" | Select-Object -First 8

Character Designation Name
--------- ----------- ----
ɑ         U+0251      LATIN SMALL LETTER ALPHA
ɒ         U+0252      LATIN SMALL LETTER TURNED ALPHA
Ά         U+0386      GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS
Α         U+0391      GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA
ά         U+03AC      GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS
α         U+03B1      GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
ᵅ         U+1D45      MODIFIER LETTER SMALL ALPHA
ᶐ         U+1D90      LATIN SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH RETROFLEX HOOK
```

### How to make it work

1. In PowerShell run `explorer (Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).Directory` to open the profile folder
2. Download the latest [`UnicodeData.txt` from the Unicode database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) and save to the above folder
3. Run `Notepad $PROFILE` and add the below lines to the end

   ```
   function Select-UniChar([string]$pattern) {
       Select-String $pattern .\UnicodeData.txt | ForEach-Object {
           $start = $_.Line.IndexOf(';')
           $end = $_.Line.IndexOf(';', $start + 1)
           $codepoint = $_.Line.Substring(0, $start)

           [PSCustomObject]@{
               Character = [char]::ConvertFromUtf32([uint32]"0x$codepoint")
               Designation = "U+" + $codepoint
               Name = $_.Line.Substring($start + 1, $end - $start - 1)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now every time you open PowerShell you can use `Select-UniChar` function to find the characters. For example `Select-UniChar "dash"`

   You can run `. $profile` to [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-) the updated profile to make the new code available immediately in the current shell

The function receives a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so you'll need some regex knowledge for advanced searching, but it's trivial to change the script to do a wildcard match or a simple text match

If you want to have a GUI view to scroll, filter, etc. then pass the output to [`Out-GridView`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.2), for example

```
Select-UniChar 'arrow' | Out-GridView
```

Note that lots of characters won't be displayable if you use the default terminal for PowerShell. You must use [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) or a better terminal instead, and possibly install more fonts to show more Unicode characters. Anyway regardless of how it's shown in the terminal, copying it still works perfectly

### Limitations:

- The output isn't sorted by usage frequency like when you press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> because that obviously requires a much more complex solution that may need to run as a service
- It doesn't work for characters that are combined from multiple code points, for example many characters in [complex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/about-complex-scripts) [scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout) like Arabic or Indic, or emojis such as

  > ‍♀️‍‍ ⚑‍☠️⚧️‍⚧️‍❤️‍‍❤️‍‍❤️‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍️‍
- It doesn't work for non-English terms like the Windows emoji picker (Looking for *chaise* won't work even if you're in French locale)
- It doesn't do [*fuzzy matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) or *word conjugation* like many modern smart emoji pickers or IMEs
- Some characters might just look as junks because there's no available font for them, but copying them then paste elsewhere still works perfectly

---

You can also print all characters like this

```
function Select-AllUniChar([string]$pattern) {
    (Select-String $pattern .\UnicodeData.txt | ForEach-Object {
        $codepoint = [uint32]"0x$($_.Line.Substring(0, $_.Line.IndexOf(';')))"
        [char]::ConvertFromUtf32($codepoint)
    } ) -join ', '
}
```

Demo:

```
D:\> Select-AllUniChar "gamma"
Ɣ, ɣ, ɤ, ˠ, Ͷ, ͷ, Γ, γ, Ϝ, ϝ, ᴦ, ᵞ, ᵧ, ℽ, ℾ, Ⲅ, ⲅ, , , , , , , , , , , ,
```

---

Here's a "simpler" version that doesn't require you to download the Unicode character data but it only works for the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane)

```
$GetUNameDef = @'
[DllImport("C:/Windows/system32/getuname.dll")]
public static extern int GetUName(
    UInt16 wCharCode,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder lpbuf);
'@
$un = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $GetUNameDef -Name "GetName" `
    -PassThru -Namespace Runtime.InteropServices
$name = [Text.StringBuilder]::new(1024)

class CharInfo {
    [char]$Character
    [string]$Designation 
    [string]$Name
}

function Select-Char([string]$pattern) {
    1..0xFFFF | ForEach-Object { if ($un::GetUName($_, $name) -gt 0) {
        $charName = $name.ToString()
        if ($charName -like "*$pattern*") {
            [CharInfo]@{
                Character = $_
                Designation = "U+{0:X4}" -f $_
                Name = $charName
            }
        }
    } }
}
```

Comment: How do I even change a directory in Powershell? I tried `cd /d B:\Projects\UnicodeApp` but it fails.

Comment: Also, `explorer (Get-ChildItem $PROFILE).Directory` fails with an error message `[...] Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1' because it
does not exist.`

Comment: just `cd B:\Projects\UnicodeApp`. And probably your powershell profile has been broken. Try fixing that with `sfc /scannow`. But it's better to install PowerShell Core instead of using the built-in PowerShell which is much older

Comment: ah I get why, it's because you don't have a profile. Just run `New-Item -Path $profile -ItemType "file" -Force` to create one. In some cases you can try `notepad $PROFILE` and save an empty file